# How to tie devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete plugin to RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, shim

I am trying to tie jquery plugin to RequireJS 
https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "autocomplete":'./vendor/devbridge-autocomplete/dist/jquery.autocomplete'
    }

     shim: {
    "autocomplete": {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
  }
)}
```

then i call it but it doesn't seems to be work

```
 require(["jquery"], function($) {
$('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: countries,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
})
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: are you seeing any javascript error in firebug or browser console

Answer (score 1):

As Autocomplete already using AMD and requires jquery as a module you have to have it defined. The configuration will look something like this:

```
require.config({ 
    baseUrl: '/libs',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9',
        autocomplete: 'jquery.autocomplete'
    },
     shim: {
        "autocomplete": ['jquery']
    },
});
```